# Change text color using if/else in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I hope someone can help me with this.I am new in javascript. I am trying to change the color of a text depending on the status in HTML file.

```
<td id="payment_status_cl" style="text-align: center; height:25px"><%=resultSet.getString("payment_status")%></td>
```

It doesn't work if I insert if/else statement in the javascript. But it will work if there are no if/else statement. For example:

This one only change the color of one status:

```
function f_color(){
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value = 'Submitted') {
document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Green";}
}
f_color();
```

This didn't work.
javascript:

```
<script>
function f_color(){
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value = 'Submitted') {
document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Green";
}
else if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value = 'Pending') {
document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Orange";
}
else if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value = 'Warning'{
document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Yellow";
}
else if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value = 'Overdue') {
document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Red";
}
}
f_color();
</script>
```

I already tried by adding div.

```
var status = document.getElementById("payment_status_cl");
function fcolor() { 
    if (status === 'Submitted') {
      document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
    }
    else if (status === 'Pending')
    {
      document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
    }  
    else if (status === 'Warning')  
    {
      document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
    }
  }();
```

but it doesn't work. I appreciate all the help given.

Comment: I think you need to change 'value' to 'innerHTML'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the Below. It will work.

1. In java Script change the equal operator (`=`) to assignment operator (`==`) for condition check.
2. Change `.value` to `.innerHTML` for getting element content.
3. Correct the syntax error , close the missing parentheses after `'Warning'`.

Check [equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) operator and [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) in javascript docs.

**Old Code:**

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value = 'Submitted') {
    document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Green";
}
```

**New Code :**

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerHTML == 'Submitted') { 
   document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Green";
}
```

```js
function f_color() {

if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerHTML  == 'Submitted') { 
   document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Green";
}
else if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerHTML == 'Pending') {
   document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Orange";
}
else if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerHTML == 'Warning'){
   document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Yellow";
}
else if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerHTML == 'Overdue') {
   document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Red";
}
};

  f_color();
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<table>
<tr><td id="payment_status_cl" style="text-align: center; height:25px">Submitted</td></tr>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @user98916 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I believe you are looking to use the `innerText` method on elements instead of using `.value`. The rest looks good

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerText = 'Submitted') {
  document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').style.color = "Green";
}
```

MDN documentation on `innertText`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work. I also try changing it to:  <code>if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerText == 'Submitted')</code>. But it also doesn't work.

Comment: What prints to the console when you do `console.log(document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerText `?

Comment: it said  `undefined`

Comment: Is you `<script>` tag right before the end of your closing `</body` tag? It could be the JavaScript is trying to executed before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Yes. I put them at `<script> code.. </script> </body>`.

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log(document.getElementById('payment_status_cl'))`? Do you see the DOM element printed out?

Comment: yes. It print `<td id="payment_status_cl" style="text-align: center; height: 25px; color: green;">`. I'm sorry for dragging this.

Comment: It looks like your `td` element might not have the text inserted into it by the time the JS code executes. You must be using some kind of HTML templating language since `<%=resultSet.getString("payment_status")%>` is not standard HTML syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` instead of `==`.

`=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison.

So you are *changing* your value instead of comparing it, and as a side effect the first `if` will always be fulfilled because the assignment expression evaluates to a truthy value.

Additionally, you need to use `innerHTML` (or `innerText` if you don't intend to work with HTML inside of your elements anyway) and not `value` (which is for the value of input fields, not the contents of elements).

Note: I see in your markup that you have a *space* before the contents of your cells! This will be part of the `innerHTML` and `innerText`! So it's best to remove whitespace before comparing, using `trim`:

```js
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').innerText.trim() == 'Submitted')
```

Comment: I just realized it just now. Thank you for pointing that out. I already change to == , but the color still did not change.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your if statements to look like this  instead of `=` use `==`
by using `=` you are assigning the value, `==` is for comparing.
And change from `.value` to `.textContent` to get the text content of the element

```
if (document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').textContent == 'Submitted')
```

Comment: Thank you. I already change to `textContent`. But only the 'Submitted' text change. The other status are still unchanged.

Comment: you should do the same to all other elements of your code if you post your html code I will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

it looks like **document.getElementById('payment_status_cl').value** value is not matching the condition use debugger if your value is correct.
and use **==** or **===** for comparison.